# How does Huber compute the $\operatorname{var}(s_n)/E[s_n]^2$ and $\operatorname{var}(d_n)/E[d_n]^2$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimators, robust, robust-standard-error, huber

<sup>(N.B. I am cross posting this question from [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772929/how-does-huber-compute-the-vars-n-es-n-and-vard-n-ed-n) since after
x days I have still not received any responses.)</sup>

How does Huber in book 'Robust statistical procedures' in chapter 1 compute the variance of certain statistical functions?
He defines the mean square deviation to be $$s_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum \left(x_i - \bar{x} \right)^2}$$
and the mean absolute deviation as $$d_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum \| x_i - \bar{x} \|.$$
Then he goes on to obtain the asymptotic relative efficiency expression ARE($\epsilon$) as shown in the photo. (So, we should have at least for arguments in the ARE(), namely,
ARE($\epsilon;n,x_i,x$),right? even if $n \to \infty.$ What does ARE() look like before we send $n \to \infty$?
How on earth does one obtain the expression in the 2nd step?)

What is $\operatorname{var}(s_n), E[s_n]$? How to obtain these expressions?

Added after comment by @whuber about actual assumptions of $x_i$'s.
Huber makes the following assumption. "We have a large, randomly mixed batch of "good' observations which are normal $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and "bad" ones which are normal $N(\mu, 9\sigma^2)$, i.e., all observations have the same mean but the errors of some are increased by a factor of 3. Now each single $x_i$ is a good one with probability $(1-\epsilon)$, a bad one with probability $\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a small number.

Finally, why does he state that just two bad observations in 1000 suffice to offset the 12% advantage of the mean square error? Is is not 5 bad observations? See:

[image: Table 1]

In the photo, values for $\epsilon = 0.005$ is 1.198 which is the (12%) I guess?

Comment: Statistical functions have neither variances nor expectations.  Functions *of random variables* like the $x_i$ are themselves random variables and therefore do have variances, *etc.* *but they depend on the distributions of the $x_i.$*  What does Huber assume about the distributions here?

Comment: @peter Re your last line -- you need to look at the $\varepsilon=0.002$ row, which has ARE just slightly above $1$, offsetting all of the approximately $12\%$ advantage that $0.876$ from the first row has over an ARE of $1$. That is $0.2\%$ contamination of this kind "undoes" the advantage you have at $0$ contamination, taking the ARE back to $1$, or no efficiency advantage.

Comment: @whuber many thanks for this comment. Yes, now it makes more sense, but still how do we compute it. Huber makes the following assumption. "We have a large, randomly mixed batch of "good' observations which are normal $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and "bad" ones which are normal $N(\mu, 9\sigma^2)$, i.e., all observations have the same mean but the errors of some are increased by a factor of 3. Now each single $x_i$ is a good one with probability $(1-\epsilon)$, a bad one with probability $\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a small number.

Comment: @Glen_b many thanks for these comments.  Are we using an implicit assumption about the 12% advantage, i.e., does this come from another computation? OR
are we talking about 1.016-0.876 =  14%,  rather than 12%? I think I'm closer to understanding it yet, not there.

Comment: In effect, he rounds 0.876 to 0.88. That 0.88 means $s_n$ has a 12% advantage over $d_n$ *when there's no contamination*. This part uses information ONLY in the first row.  He *then* looks down the remainder of the table in your post until the ARE  reaches a value close to 1, to see approximately how much contamination (of the kind he looked at there) it would take to eliminate that 12% advantage, discovering that even extremely tiny amounts suffice.

Comment: @Glen_b : impressive. many thanks *now* I understood exactly what is done!! Many thanks!!!

Comment: The figures are ratios of variances scaled to be comparable (since $d_n$ must be scaled to estimate $\sigma$ at the normal). (Ratio-1)x100 is a percentage. It's not that 13.7 (essentially 14%) is wrong, in that it is a percentage change, it's just not directly the comparison he made.

Comment: ARE basically tells you (in large samples) the ratio of the number of observations you need to estimate with approximately the same accuracy. Specifically, at 0% contamination, 88 observations using $s_n$ is about as accurate as 100 observations using $d_n$. But at 0.2% contamination it's very nearly on par ($d_n$ is a bit over one observation in a hundred more efficient, a negligible difference). At 5% contamination, you can get the same efficiency from half the data by using an estimator based on $d_n$ (or equivalently halve the variance of your estimator of $\sigma$ at a given sample size)

Comment: @Glen_b when we say $s_n$ is 12% more _efficient_ than $d_n$, what do we exactly mean? if we have 100 samples than we need 12% fewer samples are needed to determine the 'true values'?

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for the elaborate explanation for this part. I greatly enjoy this type of thinking that Huber makes. Rather very refined gentleman!

Comment: To clarify further, the use of 100 is just an example to make the percentage calculation easy. As I described, in large samples for consistent estimators the ARE describes the ratio of variances. The "A" stands for asymptotic - in some problems you may need pretty large samples to closely approach asymptotic results. Hence the ARE gives the ratio of the number of observations (due the the $1/\sqrt{n}$ effect in most forms of standard error) required to estimate  the parameter with the same accuracy (the smaller ARE means smaller sample size is needed for a given accuracy).

Comment: To be clear the use of AREs in this manner predates Huber; his contributions are manifold, but that particular notion is due to other people. Nor would he necessarily use a constant times $d_n$ to estimate $\sigma$ in general, since more efficient estimates still are available in the presence of such contamination. It is an excellent illustration of a number of ideas, including how little contamination it may take to make an 'optimal' estimator distinctly suboptimal even compared to a very simple alternative.

Comment: I corrected an error in your title. I had missed that you'd added an edit with the details of the form of contamination.  Oh ... and $\operatorname{var}(.)$ is the variance of its argument (the statistic in each instance), and $\operatorname{E}(.)$ is its expectation.

Comment: @Glen_b many thanks, but explains fully the symbolism but now comes actually the hard part of computing the expression that Huber has in the 2nd line. How did he come up with this? I will try again today to take a look but I failed the previous times so I'm unsure how to proceed strategically -- never did these type of computations beforehand. Huber is a bit advanced i think.

Comment: Sure; I haven't done any more than explain the information, I haven't attempted to answer the central question, *how to compute the variance of the estimators on each mixture* (which would be posted as an answer). I plan to come back and make an attempt if I can find some time to take a good look at the question. It's more than 35 years since I thought about this stuff. (Of course  you could always use simulation with large samples to get pretty close, if the algebra became difficult.)

Comment: @Glen_b many thanks for having clarified the 'actual question'. Impressive to see that this material hasn't gone quite out of shape. I'm thrilled to see how to algebra works out on these... looking forward to it!!

Comment: @Glen_b any chance to look over it again?

Comment: @Glen_b waiting.... :)

Comment: @Glen_b: will you have time to look into this before end of year?

Comment: @Glen_b: still there?

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry.  I do mean to deal with this quite soon.

Comment: @Glen_b: :) :) :) many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

At present I'll begin by outlining how to do it for the numerator which will at least give you some sense of what's involved, and then I'll see about doing the denominator.

Let $Y$ be a random variable distributed as an $\varepsilon$-contaminated Gaussian (mixture of Gaussians with common center). As in the question, we'll take the contaminating part having $9$ times the variance of the main distribution. That is, $f_Y(y)=(1-\varepsilon)f_X(x)+\varepsilon f_W(w)$ with $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $W\sim N(\mu,9\sigma^2)$.

Of course the estimators we're comparing will be based on $n$ such (i.i.d.) random variables, $Y_i, i=1, 2, ..., n$, but for the moment we just need to worry about the distribution of one of them.

Note that $\frac{\text{Var}(s_n)}{E(s_n)^2}=\frac{E(s_n^2)}{E(s_n)^2}-1$. Similarly for $d_n$. Presumably this will be where the "-1" terms in the numerator and denominator come from.

Now the usual sample variance is unbiased for population variance, irrespective of distribution (assuming the distribution has finite variance).

So $E(s_n^2)=\frac{n-1}{n}E(s_{n-1}^2)=\frac{n-1}{n}\text{Var}(Y)$

The expectation, expectation of the square and the variance of a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Moments) is straightforward, especially when they have a common mean.

I think we get $\text{Var}(Y)=(1-\varepsilon)(\sigma^2+\mu^2)+\varepsilon (9\sigma^2+\mu^2)-\mu^2 = \sigma^2(1+8\varepsilon)$.

So $E(s_n^2) = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2(1+8\varepsilon)$.

For the expectation, by writing the integral, we get a weighted average of the two component distribution expectations, each of which [comes down to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation#Results_for_the_normal_distribution) an expectation of a scaled [chi-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution).

That is (if I didn't make an error)
$E(s_n)= \sigma\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n-1}\frac{\ \Gamma( \tfrac{n + 1}{2} )\ }{\Gamma( \tfrac{n}{2})}[(1-\varepsilon)+3\varepsilon]$.

So $E(s_n)^2=(1+2\varepsilon)^2 \sigma^2 \frac{2(n-1)^2}{n}\left(\frac{\ \Gamma( \tfrac{n + 1}{2} )\ }{\Gamma( \tfrac{n}{2})}\right)^2$

There's a $(1+2\varepsilon)^2$ in the denominator of the image in the question, which is perhaps encouraging, and of course the result is asymptotic presumably the combined $n$-terms that don't just cancel with another one will go to $1$.

I'll try to come back and have a go at the ratio for the $d_n$ terms later and see whether it's all correct.

Comment: Happy New Year, Glen!  Nice contribution.